# Make a draggable HTML5 canvas curve area

Tags: html, html5-canvas, jquery-draggable

If I have a canvas in which an image is drawn. The image has four points in the curve. I need to make this curve area draggable.
but without use of `kinetic Js`

Image attached.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id='curveAreaDrag'  class="ui-widget-content" >
    <div id="point1" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="point2" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="point3" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="point4" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400px" height="400px"
 style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;top:0;left:0"></canvas>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#curveAreaDrag").draggable({drag:function(){save();}});
```

**Updated:**

I have four points of bezier curve. i am also scaling each point then the light black area also scaling.
i need to drag the light black area. it is not an image. it is selected area by bezier curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ Edited: To fit OP’s additional information ]**

This code uses 2 Cubic Bezier Curves and 6 control handles to let you select the eyeball in your image.

The Red handles control the curve on the top part of the eye.  The Blue handles control the curve on the bottom part of the eye.  The White handles let you anchor on the corners of the eye.  The Orange shows the resulting path (=2 curves).

Below is a picture of the app and here is a Fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/98G9F/
[image: image of application]

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
      body { font-family: arial; }
      .anchor { background: #fff; position: absolute; display: block; height: 10px; width: 10px; border: 1px solid #333; border-radius:5px;}
      .control { background: #fff; position: absolute; display: block; height: 20px; width: 20px; border: 1px solid #333; border-radius:10px;}
      .p1, .p2 { background: red; z-index: 50; }
      .p3, .p4 { background: blue; }
      .pStart { background:white;}
      .pEnd {background:white;}
      .pStart { left: 54px; top: 166px; }
      .pEnd { left: 346px; top: 189px; }
      .p1 { left: 150px; top: 39px; }
      .p2 { left: 276px; top: 97px; }
      .p3 { left: 219px; top: 227px; }
      .p4 { left: 147px; top: 224px; }
      canvas { border: 1px solid #333;}
      #start,#end2{color:green;}
      #end1{color:purple;}
      #c1,#c3{color:red;}
      #c2,#c4{color:blue;}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

        <a href="#" class="anchor pStart"></a>
        <a href="#" class="control p1"></a>
        <a href="#" class="control p2"></a>
        <a href="#" class="anchor pEnd"></a>
        <a href="#" class="control p3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="control p4"></a>

        <canvas height="400" width="400" id="canvas"></canvas>

        <p>context.moveTo(
            <span id="start"></span>);
        </p>
        <p>context.bezierCurveTo(
            <span id="c1"></span>,
            <span id="c2"></span>,
            <span id="end1"></span>);
        </p>
        <p>context.bezierCurveTo(
            <span id="c3"></span>,
            <span id="c4"></span>,
            <span id="end2"></span>);
        </p>

    <script>
      var $p1,$p2,$codeMove,$codeBez1,$codeBez2;

      $(function() {
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        $pStart=$(".pStart");
        $pEnd=$(".pEnd");
        $p1 = $(".p1");
        $p2 = $(".p2");
        $p3 = $(".p3");
        $p4 = $(".p4");
        $codeMove=$("code-move");
        $codeBez1=$("code-bez1");
        $codeBez2=$("code-bez2");

        $(".pStart, .pEnd, .p1, .p2, .p3, .p4").draggable({ 
          containment: 'parent',
          drag: function(event, ui) { renderWrap(ctx); },
          stop: function(){ renderWrap(ctx); }
        });

        var eyeImage=new Image();
        eyeImage.onload=function(){
            canvas.width=eyeImage.width*1.5;
            canvas.height=eyeImage.height*1.5;
            renderWrap(ctx);
        }
        eyeImage.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbcL4.png";

      function renderWrap(ctx) {
        var pStart=$pStart.position();
        var pEnd=$pEnd.position();
        var p1 = $p1.position();
        var p2 = $p2.position();            
        var p3 = $p3.position();
        var p4 = $p4.position();    
        render({x:pStart.left, y:pStart.top}, {x:pEnd.left, y:pEnd.top}, {x:p1.left, y:p1.top}, {x:p2.left, y:p2.top}, {x:p3.left, y:p3.top}, {x:p4.left, y:p4.top} );
      };

      function render(start, end, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(eyeImage,0,0,eyeImage.width,eyeImage.height,0,0,eyeImage.width*1.5,eyeImage.height*1.5);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
        // start-->end
        ctx.moveTo(start.x,start.y);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y,end.x,end.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        // end-->start
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(p3.x,p3.y,p4.x,p4.y,start.x,start.y);             
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        // connectors
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#999";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        connector(start,p1);
        connector(end,p2);
        connector(end,p3);
        connector(start,p4);
        ctx.closePath();
        // display code
        $("#start").html(start.x+","+start.y);
        $("#c1").html(p1.x+","+p1.y);
        $("#c2").html(p2.x+","+p2.y);
        $("#end1").html(end.x+","+end.y);
        $("#c3").html(p3.x+","+p3.y);
        $("#c4").html(p4.x+","+p4.y);
        $("#end2").html(start.x+","+start.y);       
      }

      function connector(pt1,pt2){
          ctx.moveTo(pt1.x,pt1.y);
          ctx.lineTo(pt2.x,pt2.y);
          ctx.stroke();
      }

    });
    </script>

  </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: i need tittle bit exercise on it..
Bcoz you give me images(clip). but these are points which are scalable with mouse..

but good one..

Comment: can you help more on this.

Comment: Yes, I can help.  How good is your understanding of Bezier Curves (strong or "OK" or weak)?  Knowing this will help me answer to your knowledge level.

Comment: my understanding of Bezier Curves is ok.. and i am also updated question

Comment: Ok, got it.  Results for you tonight!

Comment: Thanks... i got it.. Now i will try only to drag drop the selected light black area with all points after bind them of brazier curve. –